# Install console application where the installer wants

Tags: c#, console-application

I have published a console application and produced 3 items :

1. Application Files
2. Application
3. setup.exe

First off, am I correct in saying I can run the application directly from here without installing ? And will this use the config settings from the `application files` directory ?

Second, if I run the setup.exe, I don't have the ability to choose the install location. Is it possible to set this up ?

Comment: Copying the whole directory to another directory and running the application there, says it's already installed where I published it to (I did run the setup.exe there), so does it install directly where you run the setup.exe ?

Comment: @Amy hit publish in the properties of the project (VS 2017 console application)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This deployment technology is called ClickOnce. You can read more about it and how it works on MSDN: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/t71a733d.aspx

> First off, am I correct in saying I can run the application directly from here without installing ?

The application is indeed installed when you run `setup.exe` or `*.application`.

> And will this use the config settings from the application files directory ?

Yes. The running application will use the config file in the folder of the current version of the application.

> Second, if I run the `setup.exe`, I don't have the ability to choose the install location. Is it possible to set this up ?

No. You can't change the installation folder when you use ClickOnce. A ClickOnce application is always installed per user in the user application cache (C:\Users\username\AppData\Local\Apps\2.0).

Comment: that explains all, thank you. Suppose I need to have a different kind of publication method to allow the user to choose where to install